# StackOverflowError using Singleton in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, jetbrains-ide, kotlin-android-extensions

Can anyone tell, why I'm getting a `java.lang.StackOverflowError` using this Kotlin class? Line 41 is `if (instance == null) {`

```
class TokenHelper protected constructor() {
    var token: String? = null
    var appId: String? = null
    var installationId: String? = null
    var userId: String? = null

    companion object {
        var instance: TokenHelper? = null
            get() {
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = TokenHelper()
                }
                return instance
            }
    }
}
```

Stacktrace:

```
04-11 19:07:42.188 16142-16142/com.foo.bar.debug E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
  Process: com.foo.bar.debug, PID: 16142
  java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
      at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:0)
      at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
      at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
      at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
      at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
      at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
      at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
      at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
      at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
      at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
      at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
      at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
      at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
      at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
      at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
      at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
      at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
      at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
      at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
      at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
      at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
      at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
      at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
      at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
      at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
      at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
      at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
      at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
      at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
      at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
      at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
      at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
      at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
      at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
      at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
      at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
      at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
      at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
      at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
      at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
      at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
      at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
      at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
      at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
      at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
      at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
    at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41
04-11 19:07:42.271 16142-16142/com.foo.bar.debug D/Error: ERR: exClass=java.lang.StackOverflowError
04-11 19:07:42.271 16142-16142/com.foo.bar.debug D/Error: ERR: exMsg=stack size 8MB
04-11 19:07:42.271 16142-16142/com.foo.bar.debug D/Error: ERR: file=TokenHelper.kt
04-11 19:07:42.271 16142-16142/com.foo.bar.debug D/Error: ERR: class=com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion
04-11 19:07:42.271 16142-16142/com.foo.bar.debug D/Error: ERR: method=getInstance line=0
04-11 19:07:42.282 16142-16142/com.foo.bar.debug D/Error: ERR: stack=java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
  at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:0)
  at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
  at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
  at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
  at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
  at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
  at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
  at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
  at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
  at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
  at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
  at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
  at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
  at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
  at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
  at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
  at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
  at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
  at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
  at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
  at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
  at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
  at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
  at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
  at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
  at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
  at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
  at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
  at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
  at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
  at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
  at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
  at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
  at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
  at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
  at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
  at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
  at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
  at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
  at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
  at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
  at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
  at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
  at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
  at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
  at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
  at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(TokenHelper.kt:41)
    at com.foo.bar.helper.TokenHelper$Companion.getInstance(
04-11 19:07:42.283 16142-16142/com.foo.bar.debug D/Error: ERR: TOTAL BYTES WRITTEN: 880768
04-11 19:07:45.527 16142-16142/com.foo.bar.debug D/Process: killProcess, pid=16142
04-11 19:07:45.528 16142-16142/com.foo.bar.debug D/Process: com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$UncaughtHandler.uncaughtException:113 java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException:693 java.lang.ThreadGroup.uncaughtException:690
```

Android Studio 2.0, Kotlin 1.0.1-2

Comment: If you want to make the `TokenHelper` a singleton, simply declare it as `object` and drop the `instance` property alltogether. The compiler will take care of the boilerplate for you.

Comment: @KirillRakhman I believe your comment is the real answer. Now it's an object and I use it like `TokenHelper.INSTANCE.getToken()` (in a Java class).

Comment: I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapted from a comment on the original answer:

In Kotlin, you don't need all the boilerplate to declare a singleton. When declaring your class, simply make it an `object` like so:

```
object TokenHelper {
    var token: String? = null
    var appId: String? = null
    var installationId: String? = null
    var userId: String? = null
}
```

Then access it as follows: `TokenHelper.token` or from Java `TokenHelper.INSTANCE.getToken()`.

Answer (score 8):

You're calling `instance` getter method recursively. Change you getter definition to use [`field`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/properties.html#backing-fields) instead:

```
var instance: TokenHelper? = null
    get() {
        if (field == null) {
            field = TokenHelper()
        }
        return field
    }
```

The relevant excerpt from the documentation:

> Classes in Kotlin cannot have fields. However, sometimes it is
>   necessary to have a backing field when using custom accessors. For
>   these purposes, Kotlin provides an automatic backing field which can
>   be accessed using the field identifier:
>
> ```
> var counter = 0 // the initializer value is written directly to the backing field
>   set(value) {
>     if (value >= 0)
>       field = value
>   }
> ```
>
> The field identifier can only be used in the accessors of the property.

Comment: Thanks. I just googled "Kotlin Singleton" and came up with this solution (https://medium.com/@adinugroho/singleton-in-kotlin-502f80fd8a63#.64ssyu1by):

`private object Holder {
        val INSTANCE = TokenHelper()
    }

companion object {
        val instance: TokenHelper by lazy { Holder.INSTANCE }
    }`

Do you think that's Kotlin compliant too?

Btw: My initial code was generated by AS upon raising the "Convert to Kotlin" command.

Comment: Yes it is compliant. The IDE converter works well for very simple cases - it's outputs should always be reviewed before use.

Comment: saved me! Thanks .